# Accessing a distant model through a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 models: `User`, `Order` and `File`.

`User` and `Order` are connected to each other using a pivot table (`order_user` with columns `order_id` and `user_id`) because the same order could be associated with multiple users:

#### User.php

```
public function order() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
}
```

#### Order.php

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function file() {
    return $this->hasMany(File::class);
}
```

Files can be associated with only one order:

#### File.php

```
public function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}
```

I would like to be able to access all `File`s that are available to a specific `User`.

Is it possible to get them by doing something like `User::find(1)->order->file()->get()` (currently doesn't work)?. I've tried setting up a method in `User` as shown below but that also doesn't work:

```php
public function files() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(File::class, Order::class);
}
```

It appears that `hasManyThrough` does not work if there is a pivot table in-between.

Comment: *"It appears that hasManyThrough does not work if there is a pivot table in-between"* - That is correct; by default in Laravel, `hasManyThrough()` doesn't work with a `many-to-many`, but rather a series of `one-to-many` relationships. There's the [`belongsToDeep()` package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) that enables this though, so take a look at that and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: `User::find(1)->order->file()` will never work because `order` is a collection, so you must iterate each to be able to then do `->file()->first()`

Comment: Maybe File and User could be "orderable" ? on User side you could go orders MorphMany, and on File side MorphOne latestOfMany ?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all files accessible to a particular user, you can adjust your code to the following.

```
$user = User::find(1);
$orders = $user->order;

$files = File::whereIn('order_id', $orders->pluck('id'))->get();
```